# Phpword change word document background

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

Can I change output word document background in PHPWORD? or set background on word document, not background image OR change PHPWORD default Word2007 Theme?

Answer (score 0):

I decided problem differently change the background color of the Word document.
You can change the background color of the word document with **phpdocx**.

*for example:*

....

*//path to  the CreateDocx class within your phpdocx installation*

require_once '../../../classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$word = new CreateDocx();

*//Set the background color of the document*

$word->setBackgroundColor('FCFCFC');

*//Include a paragraph of plain text*

$word->addText('Background color.');

$word->createDocx('document');

....